# Deploy multiple wsp versions to different webapps in the same farm

Tags: deployment, solution-package, versioning

Im working on a newer version (2.0) of my sharepoint2010 wsp (which contains several features and webparts). I have dev+test servers which have a webapp each with v1.0 of wsp. In the newer version there are several updates to the existing webparts. I want to deploy it to my dev/test new webapp so that I have both webapps working with their own versions (ie both 1.0 and 2.0) until 2.0 is released. I have a couple of options:

1) change all the AssemblyVersion/AssemblyFileVersion to 2.0 of every feature,package,assmebly; Add a assemblyredirect in web.config only for the v2.0 webap. (There are about 60 references i have to change from 1.0.0.0 to 2.0.0.0)

2) deploy the v2.0 to bin instead of gac (this didnt work as i get security exceptions - cannot allowpartiallytrusted callers). My v1.0 is in gac.

Questions: 
1) Is there any other recommended way? 
2) Is #1 the only solution or 
3) Is there a easy way to make #2 work?

Comment: When deploying to bin, is your solution referencing any custom assemblies in GAC. If yes, then your assembly in GAC should have [assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers()] in assemblyinfo.cs file for that assembly.

Comment: yes, but they are third party assemblies (captcha.dll etc). I cannot modify those assemblies. But all assemblies from my solution are within the _vti_bin.

Comment: What if i rename the solution to different name...so two solutions with different name and same web parts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If side-by-side is a requirement, then you cannot use the assembly redirects. Those are designed to run new version when the old is requested. Additionally, side-by-side in SharePoint is very difficult - I would not even try it.

If you absolutely need to keep old version is some places, then you should create new solution / features and deploy them as needed. At the appropriate time, retract the old stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against running multiple versions of the same WSP in a single farm.  Although a solution can have a specified scope (e.g. web application/site etc.) parts of a WSP (namely globally deployed assemblies, files deployed to the 14 Hive) are deployed farm wide.

You may be able to get it working, but what happens when you find a bug in v2? You will spend another X amount of time confirming if it is due to sharing a farm, or if it is actually a bug.

The solution store does not use a concept of multiple versions of a solution, and assumes one is installed.  You would have to name them differently too.  This would make for maintenance hell.

If you need to compare multiple versions (say a dev branch and a prod branch), in the past I have had multiple single server farms (integration environments) (VMs pattern stamped) with the specified versions.  This is the simplest way in my mind to do this, and will make deployment/promotion easier too.